# Info window causes map to disappear

Tags: google-maps, dart, infowindow

I have created a simple Google Maps application using Dart. It was running perfectly until I added in this code to display a marker taken from the developers site. Now when the application runs the screen just goes blank and I am not sure where I am going wrong. This is the html file:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"/>
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="page.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the dart file:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

void main() {
  var myLatlng = new LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 4
    ..center = myLatlng
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ;
  final map = new GMap(querySelector("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  final contentString = '<div id="content">'
      '<div id="siteNotice">'
      '</div>'
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'
      '<div id="bodyContent">'
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large '
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '
      'Heritage Site.</p>'
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'
      'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'
      '</div>'
      '</div>';

  final infowindow = new InfoWindow(new InfoWindowOptions()
    ..content = contentString
  );

  final marker = new Marker(new MarkerOptions()
    ..position = myLatlng
    ..map = map
    ..title = 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  );
  marker.onClick.listen((e) {
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Comment: please take a look at the console, there will be multiple syntax-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an example of infoWindow at https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/tree/master/example/04-overlays/infowindow-simple

Comment: Ok I have tried to follow the example you have linked but I am still always getting a blank screen when the project runs. There are no errors coming up in the code but this is what comes up: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://127.0.0.1:3030/MapsApp2/web/page.dart
I will put up my html and dart files because they look the same as your example but obviously something is missing

Comment: Appreciate your patience as I'm sure it's obvious to you I just don't see what I need to do

Comment: I just tested once again this example and it works. The 404 is really strange, do you have both files in the same directory ?

Comment: Yes they are both in the web folder. When I replace the html code with my own file it works and the map displays but it doesn't show any of the information from the dart file, only what's in the html file which is my main problem

Comment: Are you running in dartium ?

Comment: In chromium I went to download dartium and it said if you're dart editor is up to date then dartium will already be there? I seem to have solved the problem by going back through the html code very slowly thank you again for your help